# AC alternates between blowing hot and cold in hot weather

Tags: vw, ac

When the temperature outside is cooler, say less than 80°F, and I turn my AC on, everything works great and I get nice cold air in the car.  In the late afternoons however when the temperature is above 90°F, I get cold air for 2-3 minutes then I hear a 2-5 second groan followed by about 5-10 seconds of warm air and then everything returns back to normal again with cold air blowing for another 2-3 minutes before the cycle repeats.

Anyone have ideas of how I can determine what is wrong?

The AC is the type where you just choose a fan setting between 0 - 4 (no thermostat to keep it at a set temperature).  No work has ever been done on the AC.

I can visually see the AC compressor turning on under the hood when I turn the AC on in the car.  Also worth noting is that my car sat for 3 weeks without being started while I was on vacation and this problem developed only once I got back and started driving it again.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Is the AC an auto temperature selection (ie: you set to 72° and it's supposed to keep it there) or the dummy knob where you have to adjust as needed? Also, which VW model and engine?

Comment: Sounds like the AC is cycling on and off. Any work performed on the AC?

Comment: Went ahead and updated my question with additional information.

Comment: It may be a problem with the condenser.  A/C works by compressing a vapor into a fluid, and then cooling the fluid, which has become hot as per the [combined gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_gas_law), in the condenser.  As this cooled fluid is depressurized, it becomes even colder, allowing you to generate cold air.

If there is a problem with the condenser, and it can't dissipate heat quickly enough, then the depressurized air won't be any cooler than it was when it was initially pressurized.

Comment: It is also possible that the "orifice tube" is actually getting iced over, and thus blocked.  See the section "AIR CONDITIONER PROBLEM: INTERMITTENT COOLING": http://www.aa1car.com/library/ac98.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this on a VW Passat.  The problem in that case was a malfunctioning condenser fan.  In cooler weather ambient temperature and air flow provided sufficient cooling to keep the high-side pressure within limits.  At higher temperatures, there was not enough cooling, and the pressure went high enough to trip the high-pressure switch, at which point warm air came from the vents.  So I would suggest a quick and easy check is to make sure that the condenser fan is running.

Comment: Thank you!  Turns out the larger of my two radiator fans had broken and just needed to be replaced.